# 200 OK or 201 Created : two step rest service

Tags: json, rest

I am writing a service for an e-commerce application. The service will allow customers to change the address of an existing order so that they can receive at a different address. It's a two-step process:

Step 1. GUI would send a POST request with orderNumber as path_variable and AddressId in the request body. Service would create a cart and return a cartId and updated delivery dates, updated tax amount and other info.
Some of the items may not be eligible for delivery to this new address.
The response contains an error[] to for each item to notify the UI about the delivery issue for that item if any. Also, if there is any issue for any of the items, service will not allow address change.

Now, if the customer accepts these changes:

Step 2. GUI would hit another endpoint with cartId and then cart will be submitted for further processing.

1. Should Step1 return "201 Created"(cart is being created) or "200 OK"( nothing has been created yet from customer's point of view, it's just a "tell me what would change if I change the address")
2. If there is any issue with any of the items, "status" attribute would be "failure". Should I return "failure" status in case response is 201 Created. "failure" is different from errors for which we return 4xx or 5xx.
3. Your general design suggestion around HTTP status code involving this kind of scenario.

A sample response: success ( all items can be delivered )

```
    {
  "message": {
    "id": "9fc91100-1a49-11e9-90da-ebd9192fcf6e",
    "items": [
      {
        "date": "2018-07-03T23:00:00",
        "item": "52194346",
        "quantity": 1,
        "amount": 20.65,

      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did none of the answers below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your service create a cart then you should use 201 Created. If there are issues, you should use 400 Bad Request. [This](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) is a good resource to design your API endpoints.

Comment: UI client is trying to update a resource( an address ), which is a two-step process,  why should the client get a 201 and know that something was created? Why shouldn't the response be just a 200 ( which means look at the response body and if it's a success, proceed to the 2nd step, a PUT request,  and change the address )

Answer (score 0):

Either is fine, however, given you do actually *create* something in the backend then a 201 is more appropriate (although it's generally expected return the location of the newly created resource with the request).

In terms of failures, it depends on how the request fails - if it's a result of a missing / invalid parameter in the request then a 400 is correct as it suggests to the client that they may repeat the request by making changes, if the failure is more definite i.e. something at the backend the client has no control over, then a 500 would be expected.